# How can I see what FusionInventory is reporting home?

Tags: report

A sysadmin from a higher IT department is installing a FusionInventory Agent on my clients.

I need to see a report just to verify what kind of information it's coming out.

Any way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tcpdump` / `wireshark` / `ngrep` to actually see the traffic being sent across the wire.  This is probably what I'd do.

Comment: I'm looking for a more simple approach like reading deleted files from C:\Program Files\FusionInventory-Agent\dumps\ or stuff like that... I'm trying to do so and I will report any findings...